# Installing GCC 6.0 in Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, gcc

I want the latest version of GCC, namely the GCC 6.0, for running a software. The linux version installed is 14.04 LTS. Every time I am trying to upgrade the GCC version I am ending up installing the version 4.8.4.

Comment: did you try to `sudo apt-get install gcc-6*` or better `sudo apt-get install gcc-6-base`?

Comment: @Videonauth gcc-6 is not in the repos for 14.04, it5 is only in testing.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that information, guess we never stop learning :) Then i guess compiling it from source would be a option.

Comment: It would seem to me, you can only get a test build of `gcc 6` on 16.04, with this PPA you can get to 5 but the package for 6 won't be found for 14.04 or 15.10 https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test

Comment: Full set of commands for setting up gcc 6 on Ubuntu 14.04 are on https://gist.github.com/application2000/73fd6f4bf1be6600a2cf9f56315a2d91, including `update-alternatives` so that you can switch between gcc versions as you need to